# TYPO3 : editing page title

Tags: typo3

I try to get page title and edit it like on the following example.

Page name **My tools**

Final string **my_tools** (Thus, I will be able to use it through markers in my css classes)

I know how to get page title using:

```
  HEADERTITLE = TEXT
  HEADERTITLE.data = page : title
```

But how can I transform this string?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert the case and replace some characters you may use these TypoScript settings:

```
HEADERTITLE = TEXT
HEADERTITLE {
    data = page:title
    ### replace whitespace
    replacement.10 {
        search = #\s#i
        replace = _
        useRegExp = 1
    }
    /*
    ### replace all special characters
    replacement.10 {
        search = #\W#i
        replace =
        useRegExp = 1
    }
    */
    ### transform string to lowercase
    case = lower
}
```